# Python2 (with six) metaclass and Fields with parameters

Tags: python-2.7, metaclass

I am working on creating a metaclass that should work with fields.

Based on sources on the internet, and here on StackOverflow I have come this far:

#### Metaclass

```
def getmethod(attrname):
    def _getmethod(self):
        return getattr(self, "__"+attrname).get()
    return _getmethod


def setmethod(attrname):
    def _setmethod(self, value):
        return getattr(self, "__"+attrname).set(value)
    return _setmethod


class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, based, attrs):
        ndict = {}
        for attr in attrs:
            if isinstance(attrs[attr], Field):
                ndict['__'+attr] = attrs[attr]
                ndict[attr] = property(getmethod(attr), setmethod(attr))
        return super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, based, ndict)
```

#### model

```
class Model(six.with_metaclass(Metaclass)):
    foo = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

#### Field

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, required=False, *args, **kwargs):
        self.required = required
        self.name = None

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

#### CharField

```
class CharField(Field):
    def __init__(self, required=False, max_length=0, min_length=0, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.min_length = min_length
        super(CharField, self).__init__(required, args, kwargs)
```

Now when I create a subclass of `Model`

```
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField()
```

and create an instance of `Product`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Product()
```

This works just fine.

I can even add or change the product name

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Product()
    p.name = "Another beautiful product"
```

However, when I would like to use `name` as a parameter:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Product(name="Another beautiful product")
```

An error is raised: `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

When debugging I can see that the instance of the Metaclass is created but the error is raised when the line `return super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, based, ndict)` is reached.

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Seems like your problem can be better solved with [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=descriptors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you create an interesting set of collaborative `Field` class, that can be made to work as rich, automatic properties. 
(* See bellow on that).

BUT your metaclass code only worries about the Field attributes, and does nothing to automate the parameters passed on class instantiation. When you write code like `Product(name="my name")` the "name='my name'" parameter is passed into the class's `__init__` method and `__new__` methods.  Ordinarily Python special cases `__init__` and `__new__` so that parameters to `__init__` when `__new__` is not declared are not passed up to the baseclass (`object`). Probably the use of `six.with_metaclass` is breaking this mechanism - and your `name` is getting to `object`'s contructor (and that triggers the error you are seeing).

You can fix that by customizing the `__new__` (or `__init__` if you can get away of the metaclass at all, see bellow)- Just consume your  `**kwargs`  parameters, setting whatever fields where sent, and call object's `__new__` without those extraneous parameters:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         for key, value in kwargs.items():
              if isinstance(getattr(self.__class__, key, None), Field):
                  setattr(self, key, value)
```

(see bellow - if you still need a metaclass with "six", you will likely need to 
write this code in `__new__`, not in `__init__`)

(*) Now - beyond your main problem - since you need richer properties than the allowed by Python's property, you should not  be using it - take a look on how the [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) works - basically, by creating your `Field` class defining methods named `__get__` and `__set__` you can have the additional functionality you want from your fields without the need for a metaclass at all (to that functionality - for the `__init__` call to work automatically as you want, you still will need either to customize the base `__init__` or  a metaclass)